# Using ruby to manipulate .csv files: Multiplying two columns together

Tags: ruby, csv

Can anyone think of a elegant way to take a .csv file and multiple two columns together?

I want to calculate a persons body mass index ([BMI Wikipaedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index)) from their height and weight and store it in a third column.

The formula is:

```
weight/height^2
```

Should I read the .csv line by line or make an array of arrays?

Data would look like this.

```
ID,Forename,Surname,height,weight,
0,jack,smith,177,80,
1,dan,barker,178,82,
2,ben,allen,176,93,
3,ian,bell,175,76,
4,tim,hope,174,75,
5,john,smith,165,80,
```

Thanks

UPDATE:

So far I have two arrays of height and weight

```
require 'csv'
filename = 'bmi_test.csv'

height = []
weight = []

CSV.foreach(filename, :headers => true) do |row|
  height << row[3].to_i
  weight << row[4].to_i
end
```

...and now I have two arrays and I was trying to multiply index 0 from one array with index 0 from the other.

Comment: read line by line, split, multiply, output (also line by line)

Comment: Thanks Brian- I didn't want to bias.

Comment: Currently reading an old book on FasterCSV cross referencing with 1.9.3 documentation and about 2hrs searching stackoverflow and google and still I have 3 different methods and none are even close to working

Answer (score 4):

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open("output.csv", "wb", :headers => true) do |output|
  CSV.foreach("input.csv", :headers => true, :return_headers => true) do |row|
    if row.header_row?
      output << (row << "bmi")
    else
      output << (row << row['weight'].to_f / (row['height'].to_f / 100) ** 2)
    end
  end
end
```

Or if you don't want to output a CSV, you just want the result in an array:

```
result = []
CSV.foreach("input.csv", :headers => true) do |row|
  result << (row << row['weight'].to_f / (row['height'].to_f / 100) ** 2)
end
```

You should now have an array in which you can access `result[0]['bmi']`, etc.

Comment: Oh that is magnificent. I can really learn a lot form this. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Stevancw I just added one more fix to divide the height by 100 (since it looks like you are listing cm, while BMI requires meters). Hopefully this should work now. It looks like the CSV converters feature is more trouble to use than it's worth, so I'm just using `to_f` on the appropriate fields.

Comment: Yup that's right. Actually I was using cm because i was calling to_i . I should have used to_f as in your example. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it once you have your two arrays:

```
bmi = weight.each_with_index.map { |w, i| w.to_f / height[i]**2 }
```

Comment: Thanks Mark that definitely helps get me closer. I'll give the rest a go.

Answer (score -1):

This could be done with `ruby`, but for an elegant solution use `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 { print $0 "bmi"; next } { printf "%s%.2f\n", $0, $5/($4/100)^2 }' file
```

Results:

```
ID,Forename,Surname,height,weight,bmi
0,jack,smith,177,80,25.54
1,dan,barker,178,82,25.88
2,ben,allen,176,93,30.02
3,ian,bell,175,76,24.82
4,tim,hope,174,75,24.77
5,john,smith,165,80,29.38
```

Comment: That's great stuff. Although I am new to ruby and wanted to use this as a learning exercise- it went horribly wrong.

Comment: @downvoter: Is my answer really _that_ unhelpful? The OP though it was 'great'. If you think otherwise, you should at least have the conviction to leave a comment.